# react three fiber drei typescript build errors

Tags: typescript, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to build a typescript project that uses r3f and drei as a dependency.
The modules are working fine in storybook, with no errors.

When building the project using scripts below, I get this:

```bash
Found 73 errors in 20 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/Text.d.ts:49
     1  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/index.d.ts:12
     1  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/loop.d.ts:11
     1  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/renderer.d.ts:3
     2  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/store.d.ts:31
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/cameras/CinematicCamera.d.ts:10
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/csm/CSM.d.ts:61
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/exporters/GLTFExporter.d.ts:41
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/geometries/ParametricGeometries.d.ts:3
     4  node_modules/three-stdlib/index.d.ts:82
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/accessors/CameraNode.d.ts:6
     4  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/MeshStandardNodeMaterial.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/NodeMaterial.d.ts:6
    47  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:8
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/procedural/CheckerNode.d.ts:4
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/utils/TimerNode.d.ts:2
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/ARButton.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/OculusHandModel.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/VRButton.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/XREstimatedLight.d.ts:1
```

I searched around, but I'm absolutely clueless about where these originate from or how to fix them.

My package.json

```json
{
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "npm run storybook",
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public,./dist -p 6006",
      "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
      "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
      "build": "rm -rf ./dist && tsc -d --jsx react --outDir ./dist src/index.ts"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
      "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
      "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
      "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
      "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
      "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.9",
      "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.9",
      "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
      "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
      "@types/three": "^0.141.0",
      "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
      "typescript": "^4.7.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@react-three/drei": "^9.17.1",
      "@react-three/fiber": "^8.2.0",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "three": "^0.142.0"
    }
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "lib",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

The full build output:

```bash
> rm -rf ./dist && tsc -d --jsx react --outDir ./dist src/index.ts

node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/Text.d.ts:49:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TextMeshImpl'.

49     onSync?: ((troika: TextMeshImpl) => void) | undefined;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/index.d.ts:12:187 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/user/project/node_modules/@types/three/index"' has no exported member 'XRFrame'.

12 declare const invalidate: (state?: RootState | undefined, frames?: number) => void, advance: (timestamp: number, runGlobalEffects?: boolean, state?: RootState | undefined, frame?: THREE.XRFrame | undefined) => void;
                                                                                                                                                                                             ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/loop.d.ts:11:107 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/user/project/node_modules/@types/three/index"' has no exported member 'XRFrame'.

11     advance: (timestamp: number, runGlobalEffects?: boolean, state?: RootState | undefined, frame?: THREE.XRFrame | undefined) => void;
                                                                                                             ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/renderer.d.ts:3:8 - error TS1259: Module '"/Users/user/project/node_modules/@types/react-reconciler/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

3 import Reconciler from 'react-reconciler';
         ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/react-reconciler/index.d.ts:1135:1
    1135 export = ReactReconciler;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/store.d.ts:31:86 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/user/project/node_modules/@types/three/index"' has no exported member 'XRFrame'.

31 export declare type RenderCallback = (state: RootState, delta: number, frame?: THREE.XRFrame) => void;
                                                                                        ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/store.d.ts:94:225 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/user/project/node_modules/@types/three/index"' has no exported member 'XRFrame'.

94 declare const createStore: (invalidate: (state?: RootState | undefined, frames?: number | undefined) => void, advance: (timestamp: number, runGlobalEffects?: boolean | undefined, state?: RootState | undefined, frame?: THREE.XRFrame | undefined) => void) => UseBoundStore<RootState>;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/cameras/CinematicCamera.d.ts:10:10 - error TS2305: Module '"./../shaders/BokehShader2"' has no exported member 'BokehShaderUniforms'.

10 import { BokehShaderUniforms } from './../shaders/BokehShader2';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/csm/CSM.d.ts:61:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './CSMFrustum.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

61 import CSMFrustrum from './CSMFrustum.js';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/exporters/GLTFExporter.d.ts:41:75 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.

41 declare type ImageRepresentation = HTMLImageElement | HTMLCanvasElement | OffscreenCanvas | ImageBitmap;
                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/geometries/ParametricGeometries.d.ts:3:36 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './ParametricGeometry' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import { ParametricGeometry } from './ParametricGeometry';
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/index.d.ts:82:1 - error TS2308: Module './modifiers/CurveModifier' has already exported a member named 'Flow'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.

82 export * from './nodes/Nodes';
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/index.d.ts:104:1 - error TS2308: Module './objects/Reflector' has already exported a member named 'Reflector'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.

104 export * from './objects/ReflectorForSSRPass';
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/index.d.ts:104:1 - error TS2308: Module './objects/Reflector' has already exported a member named 'ReflectorOptions'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.

104 export * from './objects/ReflectorForSSRPass';
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/index.d.ts:106:1 - error TS2308: Module './objects/Water' has already exported a member named 'Water'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.

106 export * from './objects/Water2';
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/accessors/CameraNode.d.ts:6:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../inputs/FloatNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

6 import { FloatNode } from '../inputs/FloatNode';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/MeshStandardNodeMaterial.d.ts:1:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../src/math/Color' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Color } from '../../../../src/math/Color';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/MeshStandardNodeMaterial.d.ts:2:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../src/textures/Texture' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { Texture } from '../../../../src/textures/Texture';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/MeshStandardNodeMaterial.d.ts:3:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../src/textures/CubeTexture' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import { CubeTexture } from '../../../../src/textures/CubeTexture';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/MeshStandardNodeMaterial.d.ts:4:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../src/math/Vector2' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import { Vector2 } from '../../../../src/math/Vector2';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/NodeMaterial.d.ts:6:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './nodes/RawNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

6 import { RawNode } from './nodes/RawNode';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:8:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './core/StructNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 export * from './core/StructNode';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:13:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './core/NodeLib' or its corresponding type declarations.

13 export * from './core/NodeLib';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:21:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/BoolNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

21 export * from './inputs/BoolNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:22:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/IntNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

22 export * from './inputs/IntNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:23:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/FloatNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

23 export * from './inputs/FloatNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:24:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/Vector2Node' or its corresponding type declarations.

24 export * from './inputs/Vector2Node';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:25:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/Vector3Node' or its corresponding type declarations.

25 export * from './inputs/Vector3Node';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:26:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/Vector4Node' or its corresponding type declarations.

26 export * from './inputs/Vector4Node';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:27:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/ColorNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

27 export * from './inputs/ColorNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:28:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/Matrix3Node' or its corresponding type declarations.

28 export * from './inputs/Matrix3Node';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:29:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/Matrix4Node' or its corresponding type declarations.

29 export * from './inputs/Matrix4Node';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:30:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/TextureNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

30 export * from './inputs/TextureNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:31:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/CubeTextureNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

31 export * from './inputs/CubeTextureNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:32:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/ScreenNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

32 export * from './inputs/ScreenNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:33:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/ReflectorNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

33 export * from './inputs/ReflectorNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:34:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/PropertyNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

34 export * from './inputs/PropertyNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:35:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './inputs/RTTNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

35 export * from './inputs/RTTNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:40:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './accessors/ColorsNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

40 export * from './accessors/ColorsNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:44:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './accessors/LightNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

44 export * from './accessors/LightNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:46:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './accessors/ScreenUVNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

46 export * from './accessors/ScreenUVNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:47:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './accessors/ResolutionNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

47 export * from './accessors/ResolutionNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:57:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './procedural/NoiseNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

57 export * from './procedural/NoiseNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:62:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './misc/TextureCubeUVNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

62 export * from './misc/TextureCubeUVNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:63:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './misc/TextureCubeNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

63 export * from './misc/TextureCubeNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:64:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './misc/NormalMapNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

64 export * from './misc/NormalMapNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:65:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './misc/BumpMapNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

65 export * from './misc/BumpMapNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:69:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils/BypassNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

69 export * from './utils/BypassNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:71:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils/SwitchNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

71 export * from './utils/SwitchNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:73:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils/VelocityNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

73 export * from './utils/VelocityNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:74:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils/UVTransformNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

74 export * from './utils/UVTransformNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:75:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils/MaxMIPLevelNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

75 export * from './utils/MaxMIPLevelNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:76:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils/SpecularMIPLevelNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

76 export * from './utils/SpecularMIPLevelNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:77:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './utils/ColorSpaceNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

77 export * from './utils/ColorSpaceNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:81:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './effects/BlurNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

81 export * from './effects/BlurNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:82:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './effects/ColorAdjustmentNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

82 export * from './effects/ColorAdjustmentNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:83:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './effects/LuminanceNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

83 export * from './effects/LuminanceNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:87:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/nodes/RawNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

87 export * from './materials/nodes/RawNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:88:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/nodes/BasicNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

88 export * from './materials/nodes/BasicNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:89:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/nodes/SpriteNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

89 export * from './materials/nodes/SpriteNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:90:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/nodes/PhongNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

90 export * from './materials/nodes/PhongNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:91:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/nodes/StandardNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

91 export * from './materials/nodes/StandardNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:92:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/nodes/MeshStandardNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

92 export * from './materials/nodes/MeshStandardNode';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:97:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/BasicNodeMaterial' or its corresponding type declarations.

97 export * from './materials/BasicNodeMaterial';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:98:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/SpriteNodeMaterial' or its corresponding type declarations.

98 export * from './materials/SpriteNodeMaterial';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:99:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/PhongNodeMaterial' or its corresponding type declarations.

99 export * from './materials/PhongNodeMaterial';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:100:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './materials/StandardNodeMaterial' or its corresponding type declarations.

100 export * from './materials/StandardNodeMaterial';
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:105:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './postprocessing/NodePostProcessing' or its corresponding type declarations.

105 export * from './postprocessing/NodePostProcessing';
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/procedural/CheckerNode.d.ts:4:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../utils/UVTransformNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import { UVTransformNode } from '../utils/UVTransformNode';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/utils/TimerNode.d.ts:2:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../inputs/FloatNode' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { FloatNode } from '../inputs/FloatNode';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/ARButton.d.ts:1:25 - error TS2305: Module '"three"' has no exported member 'XRSessionInit'.

1 import { WebGLRenderer, XRSessionInit } from 'three';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/OculusHandModel.d.ts:1:35 - error TS2305: Module '"three"' has no exported member 'XRInputSource'.

1 import { Object3D, Mesh, Texture, XRInputSource, Vector3 } from 'three';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/VRButton.d.ts:1:25 - error TS2305: Module '"three"' has no exported member 'XRSessionInit'.

1 import { WebGLRenderer, XRSessionInit } from 'three';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/XREstimatedLight.d.ts:1:47 - error TS2305: Module '"three"' has no exported member 'XRFrame'.

1 import { DirectionalLight, Group, LightProbe, XRFrame, WebGLRenderer, Texture } from 'three';
                                                ~~~~~~~


Found 73 errors in 20 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/Text.d.ts:49
     1  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/index.d.ts:12
     1  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/loop.d.ts:11
     1  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/renderer.d.ts:3
     2  node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/declarations/src/core/store.d.ts:31
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/cameras/CinematicCamera.d.ts:10
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/csm/CSM.d.ts:61
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/exporters/GLTFExporter.d.ts:41
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/geometries/ParametricGeometries.d.ts:3
     4  node_modules/three-stdlib/index.d.ts:82
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/accessors/CameraNode.d.ts:6
     4  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/MeshStandardNodeMaterial.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/materials/NodeMaterial.d.ts:6
    47  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/Nodes.d.ts:8
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/procedural/CheckerNode.d.ts:4
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/nodes/utils/TimerNode.d.ts:2
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/ARButton.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/OculusHandModel.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/VRButton.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/three-stdlib/webxr/XREstimatedLight.d.ts:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Build instructions weren't correct.
I had to reconfigure the entire tsconfig.json and change the build script to :

`"build": "rm -rf ./lib && tsc -p ./tsconfig.json"`